# PostgreSQL server wouldn't shutdown on Lion (Mac OS 10.7)

Tags: macos, postgresql, osx-lion

I installed PostgreSQL using Homebrew on Lion. It starts okay but wouldn't shutdown. I tried:

```
$ #started with
$ pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start
$ #tried stoping with
$ pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres stop -m immediate
waiting for server to shut down................................... failed
pg_ctl: server does not shut down
```

---

I fixed this issue by deleting the Launch Agent:

```
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/org.postgresql.postgres.plist
rm ~/Library/LaunchAgents/org.postgresql.postgres.plist
```

Comment: That is the correct fix. It worked for me on OS X Snow Leopard as well. You don't need to delete the plist though, you just have to do the unload. You can re-start it by issuing:

`$ launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/org.postgresql.postgres.plist`

Comment: @Greg: Please add your solution as an answer and accept it, so that this questions doesn't show up on the list of unanswered questions.

Comment: if installed with homebrew it may look something like this: `~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist`

Answer (score 64, accepted):

```
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/org.postgresql.postgres.plist
rm ~/Library/LaunchAgents/org.postgresql.postgres.plist
```

Comment: This worked for me too, except my Launch Agent path was: `~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist`

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me too. I also had to use the homebrew path posted by Shevaun

Comment: What causes this issue to happen in the first place?

Comment: Rather obscure way of shutting down a server.

Comment: launchctl unload + rebooting did it form me, no need to remove the LaunchAgent

Answer (score 12):

Shutting down PostgreSQL Server with `-m immediate` is a dangerous way to do it,
because “Immediate” mode will abort all server processes without a clean shutdown.

This will lead to a recovery run on restart. Try to shutdown PostgreSQL with parameter `-m fast` instead. "Fast” mode does not wait for clients to disconnect and will terminate an online backup in progress. All active transactions are rolled back and clients are forcibly disconnected

```
pg_ctl stop -D /usr/local/var/postgres -m fast
```

For more information about pg_ctl please visit
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/app-pg-ctl.html

Comment: The problem was about clean shutdown but rather about the server shutting down. Any way, its fixed and I've updated the solution in the question.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me

```
 pg_ctl -D /Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/data/ start
```

```
 pg_ctl -D /Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/data/ stop
```

Source https://sites.google.com/site/amaosblog/database/postgresql/how-to-start-stop-postgresql-9-2-on-mac-os-x-10-8-x

Answer (score 1):

If you used Homebrew to install postgresql, then as Shevauns comment on Greg's answer indicates, the correct procedure is

```
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
rm ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
```